# JBoss developer, wildfly standalone configuration

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

Can you help me starting wildfy in JBoss Developer Studio with configuration from standalone config file.

I need to use IPv6 so i set

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
```

When i run my server as standalone from cmd everything is ok

```
standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

but eclipse don't see this change.

*jboss config*

[image: jboss config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op commented: I found a solution here:

http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-wildfly-jvmparams